# Java: replace "[" "]" from text files strings

Tags: java, regex, string, replace

I'm using

```
str.replaceAll("GeoData[", "");
```

to replace "[" symbol in some strings in my text file, but I get:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Unclosed character class near index 7
GeoData[
       ^
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.error(Pattern.java:1713)
```

how can I solve this ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The method `replaceAll` interprets the argument as a regular expression. In a regular expression you must escape `[` if you want its literal meaning otherwise it is interpreted as the start of a character class.

```
str = str.replaceAll("GeoData\\[", "");
```

If you didn't intend to use a regular expression then use `replace` instead, as Bozho mentions in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5058214/java-replace-from-text-files-strings/5058233#5058233).

Comment: Thanks, one more question: what about the symbol "\" ? Should I use "\\\" ? it seems not working...

Comment: @Patrick: It's not clear from your question why you are using replaceAll. Perhaps you meant to use replace as Bozho suggests?

Comment: yeah you right. I've actually solved, I was just wondering how to replace the symbol "\" (it is a different question).

Comment: @Patrick that should be \\\\
you need to escape \ for java strings and for the regular expressions. So \\\\ will effectivly make a string of \\ which the regular expression parser then sees as escaped \

Comment: Warning: `replace` with `CharSequence` will trigger an exception if the JRE is < 1.5

Answer (score 11):

Use the non-regex method [`String.replace(..)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29): `str.replace("GeoData[", "")`

(People tend to miss this method, because it takes a `CharSequence` as an argument, rather than a `String`. But `String` implements `CharSequence`)

Comment: BTW as a side note: using `CharSequence` instead of a `String` is a very good idea when designing an *string-intensive* API. Users will be grateful if they can use `StringBuilder` and `StringBuffer` seamlessly, without the need of explicit `toString()`.